# javascript prototype and private variable

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

1. How can I make my min function working. I got banque is undefined?

Thanks.

1. List item
2. List item
3. List item

```js
function Personne(nom){
  this.nom = nom;
  var banque = 1500;
  this.add = function(number){
    banque = banque + number
  }
  this.getCpte = function() {
    return banque
  }
}

Personne.prototype.min = function(number){
  banque = banque - number
}

var me = new Personne('albert')



console.log(me)
me.add(500)
me.min(500) // got banque is undefined
console.log(me.getCpte())
```

Comment: `banque` doesn't exist outside of `Personne` function...

Comment: How can I make it exists and keeping it as a private var and using prototype method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is set up a getter for `banque` so you can use the prototype. It seems like you've already done this with `getCpte`. Just use that function to get the value of `banque` and use that in the prototype function assignment. You will also need a setter for `banque` if you want to modify the value outside the `Personne` function (this will make `banque` essentially public. To combat this, set the `min` function in the constructor if at all possible):

```js
function Personne(nom){
  this.nom = nom;
  var banque = 1500;
  this.add = function(number){
    banque = banque + number
  }
  this.getCpte = function() { //banque getter
    return banque
  }
  this.setCpte = function(value) { //banque setter
    banque = value;
  }  
}

Personne.prototype.min = function(number){
  this.setCpte(this.getCpte() - number) //set to banque - number
}

var me = new Personne('albert')

console.log(me)
me.add(500)
me.min(500)
console.log(me.getCpte())
```

What this adds is a function `setCpte` which is a setter for `banque`. This way, we can use `this.setCpte(value)` where value is the value being set to `banque`. Since you did `banque - number`, we can use the getter to get rid of the ReferenceError, and subtract number from it.

Comment: this doesn't really fix the problem, `banque` may be "private" - but it's value can be directly set  - so, in what way is it at all private? Original code you could `add`, if `min` was done the same you could subtract, but you couldn't directly set the value - that's the extent of the "privacy" the variable had - now it's just as if the variable was exposed ... I guess now you could put some logic in the setCpte function to sanitise the set value, but that's about all you're getting from this

Comment: @JaromandaX That's an huge caveat that should be noted, but I'm not sure there's any other way to do it with the OP trying to have it set in a prototype. I would just recommend setting it in the `Personne` function.

Answer (score 1):

`banque` is a local variable inside `Personne`, and you cannot access it from outside. Either put `min` inside the constructor to make it a privileged method like the others, or make `banque` a property like `.nom`.

Or just do everything through the `add` method:

```
Personne.prototype.min = function(number) {
    this.add(-number);
};
```